# how can I customize Andriod interface?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, home-screen-shortcuts, customization, user-interface

What are my options to customize the android interface? I have android lollipop.  For example, visually, I find having all the apps in one screen confusing. I have like 5 functions that I should expect to do regularly, and the rest is just cluttering the place up. that is not to say I want to remove the other apps, I just don’t want to have to look at them, while I’m trying to do something else.

It might be worth noting That I am coming from the Linux environment, where everything is highly customizable, and I am expecting android to also be highly customizable. perhaps that is flawed thinking.

There is a desktop on my tablet, that has 5 icons, an apps shortlist, google play, the link to all apps, the camera, and a mail function. Can I change what apps those are?

Comment: This depends on the phone and the launcher you are using. If you want, you could simply download one of many Android launchers out there and customize it, like you want.

Comment: Try installing the Apex Launcher and long press the icon and you can customize the icon actions to whichever app you want to open. Add your phone model information.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! There are way to many ways (oops) for customizing to put that in a single answer – which makes your question "too broad". I'd recommend sticking with your example here, asking explicitly for that (and removing the other parts of your question). Do it step-by-step. Use separate questions to ask for other things you want to change. The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you [put each question in a separate question post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154). You'll get better answers that way.

Answer (score 1):

Even in your pre-installed launcher you can remove apps from desktop (they will not be uninstalled from your tablet), sort them on your desktop any way you wish and add so many app icons to your desktop(s) how much place you have. Make a long tap on an icon and then you can move it or delete from desktop. Make a long tap on an icon in app drawer and then you can add it to your desktop.

Answer (score -1):

My favorite launcher is nova launcher. I have not updated to the new version and I'm currently running an older version so I cant say how stable the current build is. One thing you should know about replacement launchers is they do not and can not change the look and feel of your notifications area and various other system settings. To change the look and feel of your notification area you would need to get into running custom roms like cyanogenmod etc. You might also be able to use the xposed framework to mod that area but some roms such as touchwiz tend to misbehave when you do those sorts of mods.